# Click and keydown.enter at the same time

Tags: angular

I am trying to tighten up my accessibility on my website. And one thing I am trying to fix is that you can also use tab and enter to select and use e.g. buttons.

However, the way I have done it right now is not particular pretty imo:

```
<a (click)="btnState = !btnState" (keydown.enter)="btnState = !btnState" tabindex="0">My button</a>
```

So basically I have defined this `btnState` variable in my Angular `ts` component with just: `btnState: boolean`

Then when I click this button this state changes, and something happens. But as can be seen in the above code the `click` and `keydown` events are basically just duplicates. I was wondering if I could do this a little bit prettier, so I don't have to duplicate the `click` event every time I want a `keydown` event as well?

Comment: You could create your own directive for `a` elements that listens to those two events and fires one event. But, if you are ok to have the two separate properties on your `a` tag (like you currently have) I would recommend at least making a function so you don't have to change things in multiple spots if logic changes.

Comment: When the user uses a keyboard to interact with a button, it is still considered a `click` event - you don't have to take care of `keydown.enter` specifically.

Comment: If I don't use the keydown event, enter will not work. At least not in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggesting you multiple approaches:

1. Create a directive that does that particular something that you want to achieve for the click and the keydown.enter event. Use that directive in whichever place you want this event to be triggered.
2. Create a custom component wrapping your button or anchor component and listen to its click and keydown.enter event and emit it through @Output. Your custom component could be used everywhere and the emitted event could help you perform the functionality.
3. If your components where you are need this are related, you could try out some kind of inheritance/composition and perform the functionality through common code.